# Firebase Analytics - NPE in CrashReport

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-crash-reporting

I've just migrated to Firebase Analytics 9.0.0 and when tried to launch the app on emulator api10/x86, then the following exception is thrown by the services. Any ideas how to work around that?

```
05-23 15:36:44.371 1280-1280/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.szyk.myheart/com.szyk.myheart.MyHeartActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
     at com.google.android.gms.flags.impl.FlagProviderImpl.getBooleanFlagValue(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsd$zza.zzb(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsd$zza.zza(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsf.zzb(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsd.get(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.getInstance(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.zzOW(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.log(Unknown Source)
     at com.szyk.extras.activities.UniversalActionBarActivity.onCreate(UniversalActionBarActivity.java:46)
     at com.szyk.myheart.MyHeartActivity.onCreate(MyHeartActivity.java:99)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The code is nothing more than activity with:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FirebaseCrash.log("onCreate: " + getClass().getSimpleName());
}
```

Comment: This looks like a crash in Firebase crash reporting. Did you also integrated with firebase-crash reporting?

Comment: Thank you Sherlock. Yes, I did :)

Comment: Szymon, are you running the app on emulator w/o Google APIs? (aka Non-play device)?

Comment: I'm using emulator without Google Apis, however I have workaround that issue by decorating FirebaseCrash with my logging proxy, which catches the exception. Everything else from new firebase apis seems to be working fine like authenticating etc.

Comment: Can you reproduce the crash on play device (like enumerator image with Google Apis)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, using Firebase on devices or emulators without Play Services isn't a supported use case.  Crash Reporting will fail to initialize, and you will see a message to that effect in logcat when the app launches.  However, if you are also seeing a crash when calling a method after failed init, that seems like a problem we should correct.

It sounds like you are doing the best thing you can by suppressing the exception, but I'd rather not make you go through that, so I'll pass it on as feedback to the team.

Answer (score 0):

Just small correction on what Doug mentioned. Firebase Crash Reporting is not supported on non-play devices. Firebase Analytics in particular and some of the other Firebase product do support non-play devices.

Comment: Yeah, but they should not crash.